# Instantiate an object with variable number of array arguments

Tags: php

I am trying to break the array up into individual arguments and pass it to the class's constructor.  How does call_user_func_array() do this?

I've seen the method of using the Reflection class but am wondering if there is a more direct way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) is the best way to do this, the most direct way to do this, but there *is* another way:

```
function call_new_array($klass, $args)
{
  $vars = array();
  $loads = array();
  foreach($args as $i => $x) {
    $vars[] = '$v' . $i;
    $loads[] = '$v' . $i . ' = $args[' . $i . ']';
  }
  return eval(implode(";",$loads) .
              ";return new $klass(" . implode(",", $vars) . ");");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call_user_func_array(), because (as the name suggest) it calls functions/methods, but is not intended to create objects, Use ReflectionClass

```
$refClass = new ReflectionClass($class);
$object = $refClass->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

Another (more design-based) solution is a static factory method

```
class Demo () {
  public static function set_args ($args) {
    return new self($args[0],$args[1],$args[2]);
  }
}
```

and then just

```
$object = $class::set_args($args);
```

it's cleaner, because less magic and more control